# Swift when to use Performing Block Operations

Tags: swift, core-data

The [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506364-performblockandwait) states the following with "Performing Block Operations":

> func performBlockAndWait(_ block: () -> Void)
>
> **Discussion**
> You use this method to send messages to managed objects if the context was initialized using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

---

But what confuses me, Apple's documentation examples with Core Data **not always** use "Performing Block Operations".

[Saving Managed Objectets:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1)

```
do {
  try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch {
  fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```

[Fetching Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1)

```
let moc = managedObjectContext
let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

do {
  let fetchedEmployees = try moc.executeFetchRequest(employeesFetch) 
    as! [AAAEmployeeMO]
} catch {
  fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```

---

What I'm wondering is, when to use performing block operations. Is it best practice to always use them when working with a Managed Object Context. And what is the reason Apple is not always using them in their example code. Here they use it ([core data api reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)), and here not ([core data programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075)).

Answer (score 3):

You missed this part of the API documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext

> There are two exceptions:
>
> ...
>
> If your code is executing on the main thread, you can invoke methods
> on the main queue style contexts directly instead of using the block
> based API.

Comment: Sorry, I did not miss that. Could have stated my question more clearly.

"Discussion You use this method to send messages to managed objects if the context was initialised using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType."

This suggest to always use these, regardless of any exceptions. I more wondering what the best practice is. Since the apple documentation is not consistent with this.

Comment: I don't understand your reading of this. The exception is quite explicit whereas the language of the general rule is neutral with no strong language at all. Meaning that in general (since you're often doing Core Data operations on a background thread) you have to use `performAndWait`. It is also clear from reasoning about threads. What they're trying to say is the MoC method call is *already* synchronous when being called from the same thread it's configured on. `performAndWait` is therefore redundant.